# Why do I get an error when trying to use U1db with the Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I want to create an app with the Ubuntu SDK. It requires the creation of a database, so I thought it would be easy to create it with U1db.

First I had many issues finding I needed to install the `qtdeclarative5-u1db1.0` package.

Now I can `import U1db 1.0 as U1db` as [some examples show](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/qml/u1db-qt5/tutorial.html) but I can't call `U1db.Database` because I get this error message:

```
Unknow component (M300)
```

It's not very motivating… Are there some examples or tutorials showing what can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can safely ignore that error message -- annoying I know, but the component works even though QtCreator complains (and you don't get autocomplete).
2. You can find more U1db examples here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~uonedb-qt/u1db-qt/trunk/files/head:/examples/